# QML custom item state does not change when binded variable changes on C++ state

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have following custom QML item with two states:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

import si.testfirm 1.0

Item
{
    id: ueDatabaseStatusIndicator

    property string ueParamImageStatusOn
    property string ueParamImageStatusOff

    state: ueApplicationStatus.m_ueBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus===UeTypeBluetootPrinterConnectionStatus.NOT_PAIRED?
           "ueStatusIndicatorBluetoothNotConnected":
           "ueStatusIndicatorBluetoothConnected"

    Image
    {
        id: ueStatusIndicatorCurrentImage

        smooth: true

        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

        width: 96
        height: 96

        sourceSize.width: 96
        sourceSize.height: 96
    }   // Image

    states:
    [
        State
        {
            name: "ueStatusIndicatorBluetoothConnected"

            PropertyChanges
            {
                target: ueStatusIndicatorCurrentImage
                source: ueParamImageStatusOn
            }   // PropertyChanges
        },  // State

        State
        {
            name: "ueStatusIndicatorBluetoothNotConnected"

            PropertyChanges
            {
                target: ueStatusIndicatorCurrentImage
                source: ueParamImageStatusOff
            }   // PropertyChanges
        }   // State
    ]   // states
}   // Item
```

In first state, named `ueStatusIndicatorBluetoothNotConnected`, it shows **red** icon, which resembles bluetooth printer is not paired. In second state, named `ueStatusIndicatorBluetoothConnected`, it shows **blue** icon, which resembles bluetooth printer is paired with app. Now, when I run this app with following **main.cpp** file:

```
#include <QtQml>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include "database/uepeoplemodel.h"
#include "core/ueapplicationstatus.h"
#include "core/uedatabaseconnectionstatus.h"
#include "core/uebluetoothmanager.h"
#include "core/uebluetoothprinterconnectionstatus.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    UeApplicationStatus* ueApplicationStatus=new UeApplicationStatus(qApp);
    UePeopleModel* uePeopleModel=new UePeopleModel(qApp);
    UeBluetoothManager* ueBtManager=new UeBluetoothManager(qApp);

    QObject::connect(uePeopleModel,
                     SIGNAL(ueSignalDatabaseConnectionChanged(UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus)),
                     ueApplicationStatus,
                     SLOT(ueSlotDatabaseConnectionChanged(UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus)));

    QObject::connect(ueBtManager,
                     SIGNAL(ueSignalBtPrinterConnectionChanged(UeBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus::UeTypeBluetootPrinterConnectionStatus)),
                     ueApplicationStatus,
                     SLOT(ueSlotBtPrinterConnectionChanged(UeBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus::UeTypeBluetootPrinterConnectionStatus)));

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("uePeopleModel",
                                             uePeopleModel);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("ueApplicationStatus",
                                             ueApplicationStatus);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("ueBtManager",
                                             ueBtManager);

    engine.addImageProvider(QLatin1String("uePeopleModel"),
                            uePeopleModel);

    qmlRegisterUncreatableType<UeDatabaseConnectionStatus>("si.testfirm",
                                                           1,
                                                           0,
                                                           "UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus",
                                                           "Database Connection Status");

    qmlRegisterUncreatableType<UeBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus>("si.testfirm",
                                                                   1,
                                                                   0,
                                                                   "UeTypeBluetootPrinterConnectionStatus",
                                                                   "Bluetooth Printer Connection Status");

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    uePeopleModel->ueConnectToDatabase();
    ueBtManager->ueStartPairing();

    ueApplicationStatus->ueUpdate(uePeopleModel->ueFetchUsers());

    return app.exec();
}
```

in the app **red** icon is showed, which is ok, since printer is not paired, however, with the line `ueBtManager->ueStartPairing();` I start searching for bluetooth printer and the printer is **found and paired**, since slot `void UeBluetoothManager::ueSlotPairingFinished(const QBluetoothAddress& address,QBluetoothLocalDevice::Pairing pairing)` gets called as you can see from screenshot:
[image: Slot gets called]
In the last line, as you can see from screenshot, I emit signal `UeBluetoothManager::void ueSignalBtPrinterConnectionChanged(const UeBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus::UeTypeBluetootPrinterConnectionStatus& newStatus);` which is called in **main.cpp** by `ueApplicationStatus` object to update its status. Here is `UeApplicationStatus` header:

```
#ifndef UEAPPLICATIONSTATUS_H
#define UEAPPLICATIONSTATUS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QList>
#include <QDebug>

#include "../core/uetypes.h"
#include "../core/uedatabaseconnectionstatus.h"
#include "../core/uebluetoothprinterconnectionstatus.h"

class UeApplicationStatus : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(UeTypeUsers* m_ueUsers
               READ ueUsers
               WRITE ueSetUsers
               NOTIFY ueSignalUsersChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus m_ueDatabaseConnectionStatus
               READ ueDbConnectionStatus
               WRITE ueSetDbConnectionStatus
               NOTIFY ueSignalDatabaseConnectionChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(UeBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus::UeTypeBluetootPrinterConnectionStatus m_ueBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus
               READ ueBtPrinterConnectionStatus
               WRITE ueSetBtPrinterConnectionStatus
               NOTIFY ueSignalBtPrinterConnectionChanged)

private:
    UeTypeUsers* m_ueUsers;
    UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus m_ueDatabaseConnectionStatus;
    UeBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus::UeTypeBluetootPrinterConnectionStatus m_ueBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus;

public:
    explicit UeApplicationStatus(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~UeApplicationStatus();

    inline UeTypeUsers* ueUsers() const
        { return this->m_ueUsers; }
    inline UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus ueDbConnectionStatus() const
        { return this->m_ueDatabaseConnectionStatus; }
    inline UeBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus::UeTypeBluetootPrinterConnectionStatus ueBtPrinterConnectionStatus() const
        { return this->m_ueBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus; }

    inline void ueSetUsers(UeTypeUsers* const users)
        { this->m_ueUsers=users; }
    inline void ueSetDbConnectionStatus(const UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus& status)
        { this->m_ueDatabaseConnectionStatus=status; }
    inline void ueSetBtPrinterConnectionStatus(const UeBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus::UeTypeBluetootPrinterConnectionStatus status)
        { this->m_ueBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus=status; }

signals:
    void ueSignalUsersChanged();
    void ueSignalDatabaseConnectionChanged(const UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus& newStatus);
    void ueSignalBtPrinterConnectionChanged(const UeBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus::UeTypeBluetootPrinterConnectionStatus& newStatus);

public slots:
    void ueSlotDatabaseConnectionChanged(const UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus& newStatus);
    void ueSlotBtPrinterConnectionChanged(const UeBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus::UeTypeBluetootPrinterConnectionStatus& newStatus);
    void ueUpdate(UeTypeUsers* const users);
};

#endif // UEAPPLICATIONSTATUS_H
```

and its implementation:

```
#include "ueapplicationstatus.h"

UeApplicationStatus::UeApplicationStatus(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    this->ueSetUsers(new UeTypeUsers());
    this->ueSetDbConnectionStatus(UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::NOT_CONNECTED);
    this->ueSetBtPrinterConnectionStatus(UeBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus::NOT_PAIRED);

    connect(this,
            SIGNAL(ueSignalDatabaseConnectionChanged(UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus)),
            this,
            SLOT(ueSlotDatabaseConnectionChanged(UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus)));

    connect(this,
            SIGNAL(ueSignalBtPrinterConnectionChanged(UeBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus::UeTypeBluetootPrinterConnectionStatus)),
            this,
            SLOT(ueSlotBtPrinterConnectionChanged(UeBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus::UeTypeBluetootPrinterConnectionStatus)));
}   // constructor

UeApplicationStatus::~UeApplicationStatus()
{
    delete this->ueUsers();
}   // destructor

void UeApplicationStatus::ueSlotDatabaseConnectionChanged(const UeDatabaseConnectionStatus::UeTypeDatabaseConnectionStatus& newStatus)
{
    this->ueSetDbConnectionStatus(newStatus);
}   // ueSignalDatabaseConnectionChanged

void UeApplicationStatus::ueSlotBtPrinterConnectionChanged(const UeBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus::UeTypeBluetootPrinterConnectionStatus& newStatus)
{
    this->ueSetBtPrinterConnectionStatus(newStatus);
}   // ueSlotBtPrinterConnectionChanged

void UeApplicationStatus::ueUpdate(UeTypeUsers* const users)
{
    this->ueSetUsers(users);
}   // ueUpdate
```

The question is, why images are not switched on QML side inside custom item `ueDatabaseStatusIndicator`, which code is listed first?

Comment: A friendly advice, those great walls of code will not do you favors when it comes to solving your problem. Try to isolate the problem and produce a minimal example reproducing it. This way you don't punish the people who want to help you out by having to go through all that irrelevant code.

Comment: @ddriver I am aware but I could not shrink it since these classes are currently point of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be because of the way you are initialising your application. You are starting the event loop after emitting the signals. Try this.

```
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

QTimer::singleshot(150, this, [&]() {
  uePeopleModel->ueConnectToDatabase();
  ueBtManager->ueStartPairing();
  ueApplicationStatus->ueUpdate(uePeopleModel->ueFetchUsers());
});

return app.exec();
```

This is just my guess. Best of luck.

---

**update**

```
inline void ueSetBtPrinterConnectionStatus(const UeBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus::UeTypeBluetootPrinterConnectionStatus status)
{ 
    m_ueBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus=status; 
    emit ueSignalBtPrinterConnectionChanged(m_ueBluetoothPrinterConnectionStatus);
}
```

You must remove the `connect` calls as this creates a infinite loop.

Comment: I had to add `-std=c++11` in project file because of [lambda operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), but it does not work, icon is still **red** and does not change to **blue**.

Comment: you are not emitting any signals from `UeApplicationStatus` class. why you are connecting signals? see my update..

Comment: I've taken into account your **update** and removed `connect` statements set from **UeApplicationStatus.cpp** IT WORKS NOW!